# threading.excepthook args.exc_traceback is None

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, exception, hook

I'm trying to override `threading.excepthook`.  It sort of works, but my `custom_hook()` receives `None` as the traceback.  The Python documentation says that this is possible.  But, *why*?  How can I get the real traceback in `custom_hook()`?

My ultimate goal is to print a timestamp with each stack track (for both system exceptions and my custom exceptions).  The output needs to go to `stderr`.

If I run the following code:

```
from time import sleep
import threading
import traceback


# target function that raises an exception
def work():
    print('Working...')
    sleep(1)
    # rise an exception
    raise Exception('Something bad happened')


# custom exception hook
def custom_hook(args):
    # report the failure
    print('timestamp')
    print(traceback.print_tb(args.exc_traceback))


def main():
    # set the exception hook
    threading.excepthook = custom_hook
    # create a thread
    thread = threading.Thread(target=work)
    # run the thread
    thread.start()
    # wait for the thread to finish
    thread.join()
    # continue on
    print('Continuing on...')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get this output:

```
/Users/msarrel/PycharmProjects/pychansim/venv/bin/python /Users/msarrel/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.2/scratches/scratch_1.py 
Working...
timestamp
None
Continuing on...
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.18/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.18/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 917, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/msarrel/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.2/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 11, in work
    raise Exception('Something bad happened')

Process finished with exit code 0
```

For some reason the traceback is printed after the `thread.join()`.

If I don't try to print the traceback in `custom_hook()`:

```
from time import sleep
import threading
# import traceback


# target function that raises an exception
def work():
    print('Working...')
    sleep(1)
    # rise an exception
    raise Exception('Something bad happened')


# custom exception hook
def custom_hook(args):
    # report the failure
    print('timestamp')
    # print(traceback.print_tb(args.exc_traceback))


def main():
    # set the exception hook
    threading.excepthook = custom_hook
    # create a thread
    thread = threading.Thread(target=work)
    # run the thread
    thread.start()
    # wait for the thread to finish
    thread.join()
    # continue on
    print('Continuing on...')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following output instead:

```
/Users/msarrel/PycharmProjects/pychansim/venv/bin/python /Users/msarrel/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.2/scratches/scratch_1.py 
Working...
timestamp
Continuing on...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

In this case, the traceback isn't printed at all...

*Why*?